# How can I Bind one Selector and event to a radio button

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am Editing this question Clearly  I have "radio2" checked  as default on loading the document. After that the user can select "radio1".

I have two parts of code:

**Handle when  checked**

```
if($("#radio2:checked") && $("#somehidden").val()==="ABC") {
     //Do some Set of actions 
    $("#txt1").val("BCD");
    $("#txt2").val("ZXY");
}
```

**Handle When Clicked**

```
$("#radio2").bind('click',function(){
  if($("#somehidden").val()==="ABC") {
    $("#txt1").val("BCD");
    $("#txt2").val("ZXY");
  }     
});
```

I have written the first part of the code for on load the document I have same set of actions and these actions appear the same when we click that we have seen in the second part of the code. My question is I have to remove the First part of code why because as I already have the hidden value condition on the click. How can I handle both?
I am using `trigger()` to select it. I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) to trigger the event.

```
$("#radio1").bind('click',function(){
    alert("Checked");
}).trigger('click'); //on ready;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#radio1").bind('click',function(){
    alert("Checked");
  });

  $("#radio1").click(); // on ready
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  var $radio1 = $("#radio1"),
      actionIfChecked = function() {
        alert("Checked");
      };

  $(window).load(function() {
    if ($radio1.is(":checked")) actionIfChecked();
  });

  $radio1.click(actionIfChecked);
});
```

Edit: Its possible I misinterpreted the question, judging by the other responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $("#radio1").bind('click',function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked") {
       // Do your stuff
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: this is just binding, and once you click it, this code checks if it is "checked", you can click to uncheck as well, but if you put some code in that if, it only fires when it is checked. Did I get your question correctly ?

Comment: I have to get Checked called first

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but it might help:

```
if($("#radio1").attr("checked")){
    alert("Checked");
}

$(function() {
    $("#radio1").bind('click',function(){
        if(this.checked){
            alert("Checked");
        }
    });
});
```